# How can I say that I want to have my food here when I'm in a cafe, not "para llevar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, preguntas, cortesía, identificación-de-término

Is it simply "para aquí"?

I often get asked something when I'm making a payment, but I can't make out what it is they're asking me. I assume that that's related to "for here or for taking away", but what that is precisely? And how can I ask that and respond to that in Spanish?

Comment: Are you saying  you don't understand something being said **to you**? Where is this question being asked?What country?

Comment: @Lambie, "Are you saying you don't understand something being said to you?" --> yes

Comment: @Lambie, the country isn't important because **I can't catch the question/s** in the first place

Comment: The question depends of the country. At least I'm used to hear "¿para servir o para llevar?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer. It means

> You want this for here or to go?

So, this is always said when you buy food in shops, but not shops like supermarkets, but shops where you can actually eat the food inside (if you want).

So you've got two options:

- Taking your food to a table and eat it there.
- Having the food packed so that you can take it away to eat it later, wherever you want.

So the salesman is basically asking wether you are going to eat the food there or you want to take it away (having it packed, "to go").

The same applies for drinks.

---

The usual sentence is

> ¿ (Es) para tomar aquí o para llevar?

which means

> (Is it) for here or to go?

Because the salesman needs to know if (s)he has to pack it for you and put it in a bag, or just serve you  the food directly.

So the answer is easy: it is in the very question.

> Para tomar aquí = for here.
>
> Para llevar = to go.

You can always add "por favor" at the end, that's more polite, but that's pretty much it. It's quite simple.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that some places may charge extra for taking the food/drink to a table, while this is not an extremely common thing, it does happen.

Comment: Does it? Never found one. Don't go to those places haha.

Answer (score 3):

A common binomial used for this case is *¿Para servir o llevar?* The one you need is *¿Para servir?*

However, this, depending on the region and on what you're having, may show variations:

> —¿Para **servir** (aquí)?
>   —¿Para **tomar** (aquí)?
>   —¿Para **comer** (aquí)? (I wouldn't use this, but I listed it anyway.)

And you respond to these with a simple *Sí*; you don't need anything more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know exactly what you are actually being asked. You `assume that that's related to "for here or for taking away"` but you could be being asked if you want a printed receipt or something else with your order.

> Es eso todo?
>
> Quiere algo más?

Assuming that you are actually being asked if you want if "for here or to go" you would be hearing questions like:

> Lo va a tomar aquí?
>
> Lo quiere para llevar?
>
> Se lo pongo en una bolsa?

To which you could simply reply

> (Es) para **tomar** aquí

since one of the meanings of [tomar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZzcN8W0) is

> 6. tr. Comer o beber. Tomar un desayuno, el chocolate. U. t. c. prnl.

To make sure that that is actually what they are asking, you could say

> Pregunta si lo quiero para llevar? No, es para tomar aquí.
>
> Pregunta que si es para tomar aquí? No, lo quiero para llevar por favor.

You could say [consumir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AT2BY5W) instead of *tomar*

> 2. tr. Utilizar comestibles u otros bienes para satisfacer necesidades o deseos.

but it sounds much less pleasant ("to be consumed here" instead of "to have it here".

You could additionally say

> No lo necesito para llevar

And they will understand that you'll have your food/drink at the cafe.

Comment: But the OP says she or he is being asked a question. It would be useful to know where....

Comment: See the exchange under the question? How would you respond to that? Isn't context important?